# Prove that $T^*$ is injective iff $ImT$ Is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let X,Y be two normed spaces, and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ a bounded linear operator. prove that the adjoint operator $T^*$ ($T^*f(x)=f(Tx)$ is injective iff $ImT$ is dense

any help would be great guys.
I did try a bit to solve it myself, using the deffinition of injective and going straightforward. It didn't work. I suppose that I have to use some theorem in order to solve it, and i hoped you could at least tell me which.

Thanks!

Could anyone give any kind of hint please?

Comment: The title of your question does not really match the actual question (maybe the statement of the current question is used to prove the result in the title?). Is this intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\operatorname{Im}T$ is dense and let $f\in Y^*$ with $T^*(f)=0$. This means that
$$
f(Tx)=0
$$
for all $x\in X$. Now, let $y\in Y$; by assumption, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}T(x_n)$. Apply continuity of $f$ and $T$ to conclude.

> $$f(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(Tx_n)=0.$$

The converse is (a special case of) the Hahn-Banach theorem: if $y\in Y$ doesn't belong to the closure of a subspace $U$, then there exists a linear functional $f\in Y^*$ such that $f(y)\ne0$, while $f$ vanishes on $U$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the kernel of $T^*$ is the annihilator of $\operatorname{Im} T$. Show that the only closed subspace with $0$ annihilator is the whole space.

Here, for a set $S \subset Y$, the annihilator of $Y$ is defined to be $\{\alpha \in Y^*\vert \alpha(y) = 0 \text{ for } y \in S\}$.

Comment: Hey, could you please explaine what did you mean by annihilator? As far as I know annhilator relates to a Ring-structure. what is the structure you are reffering to?